# Which version of PvX Wiki is current?

Tags: guild-wars

I used to use PvX wiki extensivly, I even built a site before they launched which did something similar before I got out-coded. Anyway, I notice now that the old pvxwiki.com is gone and redirects to, http://pvx.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page

But I also noticed that the build packs page on Wikia now has a note to here, http://www.gwpvx.com/PvX_wiki which seems to be a port of the old site.

Does anyone have any idea which is current?

Added to that my old wiki page seems to have moved also to here, http://guildwars.wikia.com/wiki/User:Neon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the folks that managed the PvXWiki have joined the mass exodus of other sites, such as [NetHackWiki](http://nethackwiki.com) and [WoWPedia](http://www.wowpedia.org) in moving *away* from Wikia. In general, these migrations have been the result of Wikia's new templates, with their substantially increased advertising presence, and unwelcome impact on page layouts. It seems that the PvXWiki, like WoWpedia, is now being hosted by [Curse](http://www.curse.com). As a user of the old Wikia site, you should be able to reclaim your account at the new site using [this form.](http://www.gwpvx.com/Special:UserMigration)